# After Create new theme in magento

Tags: magento2

Replace App And Pub Folder of Theme In Magento2. 
After that Run Following Command :

- sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- sudo php bin/magento cache:clean

After that Using **Admin Panel-> CONTENT -> Configuration** Select new default theme. But in front NOt Display.

display only "CMS homepage content goes here.[image]"

Answer (score 0):

Seems the selected **cms page** for the store does not showing.

You have to check two settings:

### Setting 1:

Goto **Admin>General> Web**  and select Scope from `Scope:`(*top left of page*)

Then go to **Default Pages**,Select **CMS Home Page** from dropdown.

### Setting 2:

If first setting existing then check

Goto `Admin>Content>Content>Pages` select page, then check `Enable Page` = `Yes`

And check Store view/Website from at `Page in Websites`.